# Core Data Predicate iOS 4 -> works iOS 5 -> crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, subquery, predicate

I am working on an app, which makes use of a Core Data Model and I am encountering a problem while using an `NSPredicate`.

My data model looks like this:

```
Asset
1 to 1 relationship with SearchAsset
many to many relationship with SearchTerms
```

`Asset` has several fields like unique_ID, URL, etc.. while `SearchTerms` has only one field called terms. `SearchAsset` has no fields, it only points to an Asset.

When I want to do a search I call the following code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    dbgPrint(@"Search text: %@", searchText);
    if ([searchText length]>0){
        NSString *prefix = [SearchTerm normalizedTerm:searchText];


        NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]<5.0){
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"asset != NULL && SUBQUERY(asset.searchTerms, $x, $x.term BEGINSWITH %@).@count > 0",prefix];
        } else {
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"asset != NULL && SUBQUERY(asset.searchTerms, $x, $x.term BEGINSWITH %@).@count > 0",prefix];
        }

        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetcher = self.searchResultsController;
        [theFetcher.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error=nil;
        [theFetcher performFetch:&error];
        if (error){
            dbgPrint(@"Error performing fetch");
            dbgAbort();
        } else {
            NSUInteger count=[[self.searchResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
            dbgPrint(@"Fetching of %d sucessful", count);
            [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:[SearchAsset cacheName]];
            [self.gridView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

On iOS 4 it works fine but on iOS 5 i get the following error:

```
Core Data: annotation: -executeRequest: encountered exception = I/O error for database at /Users/markuspfundstein/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/87DE3380-A49F-493E-B9FF-77DFBC65669E/Documents/TopNotch-1.0.2.2.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t2.ZTERM' with userInfo = {
NSFilePath = "/Users/markuspfundstein/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/87DE3380-A49F-493E-B9FF-77DFBC65669E/Documents/TopNotch-1.0.2.2.sqlite";
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 1;
}
```

It seems that the predicate parser works different on iOS5 but I was not able to find any notes from Apple about that problem.

**Update**

HALFWAY SOLUTION: the predicate works if I fetch from the Assets directly without a reference to SearchAsset. The predicate looks than like this:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"SUBQUERY(searchTerms, $x, $x.term BEGINSWITH %@).@count > 0",prefix];
```

In my opinion that is a bug in the iOS 5 Core Data library. It's unfortunate, because I have to rewrite big parts of my database model now...

Comment: If you take out the `"asset != null"` part of your predicate, do you still get the error?

Comment: nope sorry .. the predicate works if i test for asset == NULL. than i get a whole bunch of results back.. so it is about that forward statement asset.searchTerms.term ...

Comment: Is it possibly a case sensitivity issue? Did you try `"Asset"` instead of `"asset"`? Maybe they started being stricter with case in iOS 5...

Comment: nope also not.. i am always very sensitive about case sensivity :-) that was one of the first things i checked..! It is also weird that when i run the parsed iOS 5 code through my SQL Lite database application, the same error occurs. The parsed iOS4 code works.. it MUST be an bug in the core data lib..

Comment: If you can make a very simple test application demonstrating the bug, zip it up and submit it to Apple. http://bugreport.apple.com/